# play framework NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: scala, utf-8, playframework-2.0, typesafe-stack

I've downloaded the typesafe stack for windows and created a new project. When I fire up sbt and try to run the new unmodified application there's this error:

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/netty/channel/ChannelFactory
```

just out of curiosity I also tried to compile the project. The error is different:

```
[error] IO error while decoding .....welcome.template.scala with UTF-8
[error] Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option
```

What can I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in my script there is one -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, but I also encounter the same error:

[error] IO error while decoding .....***.java with UTF-8 
[error] Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classpath prblem. Make sure the netty jar is included in there

Comment: I've only added java and scala to my path and thought the typesafe stack would do the rest. Sbt seemed to download and configure all the dependencies. However could you please enlarge a little bit on what I should do ? A link would be great.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try to add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to your sbt script and see if that helps?

I also tweaked the template, please discard the app folder and try to create a new app with g8

Comment: I don't know how to modify the sbt script. Where do I find the config file ? Moreover I deleted the old example folder and ran g8 again. The run error is the same. But compile now fails with a new error: The log refers to an error connected with akka. I'll update the question accordingly as soon as I'm back on my working machine. Since it's 11pm in Germany I wish you a good night ;)

Answer (score 0):

After tweak default template is working but if i will add "ä" character to the file

```
@main("Welcome to ü") {
    @welcome(message)
}
```

It will throw error:

> IO error while decoding /.../views/html/index.template.scala with
>   UTF-8 Please try specifying another one using the -encoding option

Comment: it's working for me. Have you added  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to your sbt script?

Comment: At last i found the place and fixed my encoding problem:) /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.11.2/bin/sbt  and i added encoding **exec java -Xmx512M ${SBT_OPTS} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.11.2/libexec/sbt-launch.jar "$@"**. About SBT configuration http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup